# A better way to set flags

Tags: c

I need to use some flags in my code. To make it a bit clearer, I am looking to set the flags in some structure, and I need to match the following needs:

1. The flag representation in the structureis hidden.
2. The following methods are provided (or the same idea at least): `setFlag(structWithFlags *, ACTION_FLAGS )`,
   `isFlagSet(structWithFlags *, ACTION_FLAGS)` and `removeFlag(structWithFlags *, ACTION_FLAGS)`
3. The structure should not contain a "magic number" that defines the size of the flag bytes, since the number of flags may vary, when compiling for different projects.

In general, this is serving as part of a general module, used by many different modules, in many different combinations.

Currently, my method to achieve that is as follows:

projectSpecificNeeds.h:

```
typedef enum ACTION_FLAGS {
    ACTION_FLAG_NO_1,
    ACTION_FLAG_NO_2,
    //.. etc.
    FLAG_LAST
}ACTION_FLAGS ;
```

genericModuleThatServesEveryBody.c:

```
#include <limits.h>
#include "projectSpecificNeeds.h"
typedef struct structWithFlags {
    // Some irrelevant fields
    // each flag is represented by one bit in the flagByte array
    char flagBytes[FLAG_LAST / CHAR_BIT + 1];
}structWithFlags ;

structWithFlags * getStructWithFlags() {
    return calloc(sizeof(structWithFlags));
}

// Bitwise OR between the relevant flag byte and the flag
void setFlag(structWithFlags * st, ACTION_FLAGS flag) {
    st->flagBytes[flag / CHAR_BIT] |= 1 << (flag % CHAR_BIT);
}

// return the AND between the relevant flag byte and the flag 
char isFlagSet(structWithFlags * st, ACTION_FLAGS flag) {
    return st->flagBytes[flag / CHAR_BIT] & ( 1 << (flag % CHAR_BIT));
}

// Bitwise AND between the relevant flag byte all bits except of the flag
void removeFlag(structWithFlags * st, ACTION_FLAGS flag) {
    st->flagBytes[flag / CHAR_BIT] &= ~(1 << (flag % CHAR_BIT));
}
```

It works well, and I met no problem with it until now. But I wonder whether there's some more elegant / readable yet memory saving method to implement this functionality.

Comment: Is it ok to impose a constraint that the flag's integral value must be a power of 2?

Comment: Does it really _have_ to be in a structure?  Assuming you will have a small amount of distinct values, you can just fit that into a 32-bit data type (or smaller) such as an `int`.

Comment: @VictorT. - this will create a limitation which I don't really interested in, but I'm open for suggestions... :)

Comment: @JeffMercado - It's in a structure since this is not the only thing that passes, I tried to focus on the flag part. Also - there are over 32 flags, and it varies from project to project.

Comment: @MByD: Are these 32+ flags all related and can't be separated into separate groups (and threfore different enums)? I'd argue they can but can't really give any advice here as I don't know how you're using them.

Comment: @JeffMercado - This is a tough one - you're basically right, in each project they may be arranged in some groups, but I can't know that for sure for all projects, and surely it's NOT gonna be the same flags / groups in different projects.

Comment: You could use pre-processor macros. Then, since the flag numbers are constants, the expressions could be simplified by the compiler at the compile time while still maintaining the readability. If you can't pack the flags into uint(32|64)_t, that is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How many flags do you need? If you can settle with only 32 or 64 different flags instead of a generic-length array of flags, then it would probably be better to allocate the flags in a simple unsigned long, to save your program from all the runtime calculations.

The main efficiency problem in your code is that the compiler can't know the value of the "flag" parameter, so it must calculate division and modulo in runtime to know where to set the flag.

Your code is also limited to one flag set at a time. A common way to write code like this from the caller's side is `setFlag (&the_struct, FLAG_THIS | FLAG_THAT);`. The whole Windows API uses flags like that, with bitwise OR. If you stored the flags in an unsigned long that wouldn't be a problem, as you wouldn't need to index the flag array. Then the caller wouldn't need to call your function over and over to set several flags at the same time.

Surely it must be ok to group flags into 32/64 bit variables, related to a specific code module?

Comment: +1 to 'Surely it must be ok to group flags into 32/64 bit variables, related to a specific code module?'

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. The disadventeges you mentioned are known to me, and maybe I should have add them in the consideration, unfortunately, I know that there might be more than 32 flags, and I need oit to be generic, so I can't really set the flags before. The fact that I can set only one flag at a time is a con, but the fact that those calculations are needed at runtime don't bother me much (in this specific scenario).